# Laravel validator - how to return only errors for certain fields?

Tags: laravel

I have one form in Laravel in which I have a couple of fields marked as "required" in the validation rules of the controller. When the field is empty, Laravel highlights that field with a red border and adds the `is-invalid` CSS class (which is good). When the field is filled with anything, it adds a green border and `is-valid` CSS class.

However, for some fields, I would like to hide the green border when they're filled with something (success response) and only show the red border (failed response) when they're empty.

**Is there a way to silence the success response for some fields in the validator rules / controller?**

Comment: Isn't that maybe done in your view/blade file that displays the form? Did you check that file for `is-valid`?

Comment: @brombeer I did - I can only see things like "@error('month') is-invalid @enderror" in the input field classes, but nothing for the "is-valid" ones. I assume it's done by JS reading responses and works globally on all fields. So I thought that maybe I could modify the controller to send only error responses for certain fields, but I don't even know if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScript code is adding a css class to your inputs like: `'is-valid', 'valid', 'other-valid-class'`.

Just control by JavaScript when add the `is-valid` class.

Check your Script insert in the blade or the `@section('scripts')`.

If in the controller your validations return a fail (on these input) should be shown as red border.